# Layout problem in the question list

Tags: bug, design

I currently get (probably wrong= line breaks in the question list:
[image: wrong layout]

The second question has a line break which looks wrong. This happens for a few other questions in the list as well.

- Browser: Vivaldi 1.15
- Operation System: Linux
- No User Scripts / User Styles for Stackoverflow.